# Golang: How to construct a struct for Elasticsearch pipeline attachment

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I'm constructing a struct to send a put message to Elasticsearch for pipeline attachment.

This is the json that I'm supposed to send it to ES:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment 
{   
    "description": "Process documents",   
    "processors": [
        {
            "attachment": {
                "field": "thedata",
                "indexed_chars": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "attachment.title",
                "value": "{{ title }}"
            }
        },
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "attachment.author",
                "value": "{{ author }}"
            }
        },
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "attachment.url",
                "value": "{{ url }}"
            }
        },
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "attachment.cover",
                "value": "{{ cover }}"
            }
        },
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "attachment.page",
                "value": "{{ page }}"
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

Do I really need to make a struct and marshal it in order to put the message? (I'm coming from Python). Setting up pipeline is a single time process.

I'm constructing structs like this in Go:

```
type AS struct {
    Description string

}

type ASP struct {
    Processors 
}

type ASPA struct {
    Attachment []ASPAF `json:"attachment"`
}

type ASPAF struct {
    Field string `json:"field"`
    IndexedChars uint64 `json:"indexed_chars"`
}

type ASPS struct {
    Set []ASPSF `json:"set"`
}

type ASPSF struct {
    Field string `json:"field"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

If you can see the code, I'm stuck at `ASP struct` and `AS struct` **for processors and rounding up as attachment struct with description**.

Could someone guide me? I'm not even sure if I'm right with the above structs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to do this successfully,

I have constructed structs like this:

```
type AS struct {
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Processors []ASP `json:"processors"`
}

type ASP struct {
    Attachment ASPA `json:"attachment"`
}

type ASPA struct {
    Field string `json:"field"`
    IndexedChars int64 `json:"indexed_chars"`
}

attachment := &AS{
    Description: "Process documents",
    Processors: []ASP{
        ASP{
            Attachment: ASPA{
                Field: "thedata",
                IndexedChars: -1,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Then I sent a put request similar to this 
https://github.com/DaddyOh/golang-samples/blob/master/httpClient.go

I got the result:

```
{"acknowledged":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [logrus](https://github.com/sohlich/elogrus) package which has elastic search hook and is simple enough.